# What does "Sync Google+ Notifications" do?

Tags: sync, google-account, accounts, google-plus

I've recently upgraded to 2.3.7 and noticed a new setting under the Google accounts sync options.

> Settings->Accounts & sync->my google account

As well as sync contacts, GMail etc it now also has a checkbox for

> Sync Google+ Notifications

Does anyone know what this setting does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obvious: It syncs Google+ notifications if you have a Google+ account.  For example, comments on one of your posts (depending on your notification settings).

Not as obvious: You need [the Google+ app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus) for it to work.

Comment: Ok thanks. Seems odd wording to me as sync is really about data. Notifications aren't data they just tell you something has happened. But from what you are saying it will sync the data (comments etc) related to the notification.

Comment: @sickgemini I don't know the specifics of what's synced, but to my mind notifications are data like anything else.

Comment: Perhaps it is syncing the unread-flags of the notifications?